# Getting Activiti library version mismatch error when used 7.1.0.M6 version of Activityi Workflow Engine with Spring Boot 2.1.7.Release version

Tags: java, spring-boot, activiti

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.7.Release version along with Activiti Workflow Engine 7.1.0.M6 version and when I run the spring boot application I get the error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngine': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.activiti.engine.ActivitiWrongDbException: version mismatch: activiti library version is '7.1.0-M6', db version is 6.0.0.4 Hint: Set <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" to value="true" or value="create-drop" (use create-drop for testing only!) in bean processEngineConfiguration in activiti.cfg.xml for automatic schema creation
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:178) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:101) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1674) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1249) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
> ... 84 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.activiti.engine.ActivitiWrongDbException: version mismatch: activiti library version is '7.1.0-M6', db version is 6.0.0.4 Hint: Set <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" to value="true" or value="create-drop" (use create-drop for testing only!) in bean processEngineConfiguration in activiti.cfg.xml for automatic schema creation
> at org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession.dbSchemaCheckVersion(DbSqlSession.java:937) ~[activiti-engine-7.1.0.M6.jar:na]
> at org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession.performSchemaOperationsProcessEngineBuild(DbSqlSession.java:1451) ~[activiti-engine-7.1.0.M6.jar:na]
> at org.activiti.engine.impl.SchemaOperationsProcessEngineBuild.execute(SchemaOperationsProcessEngineBuild.java:28) ~[activiti-engine-7.1.0.M6.jar:na]
> at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker$1.run(CommandInvoker.java:37) ~[activiti-engine-7.1.0.M6.jar:na]
> at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.executeOperation(CommandInvoker.java:78) ~[activiti-engine-7.1.0.M6.jar:na]
> at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.executeOperations(CommandInvoker.java:57) ~[activiti-engine-7.1.0.M6.jar:na]
> at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.execute(CommandInvoker.java:42) ~[activiti-engine-7.1.0.M6.jar:na]
> at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.TransactionContextInterceptor.execute(TransactionContextInterceptor.java:48) ~[activiti-engine-7.1.0.M6.jar:na]
> at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:59) ~[activiti-engine-7.1.0.M6.jar:na]
> at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:47) ~[activiti-spring-7.1.0.M6.jar:na]
> at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
> at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:45) ~[activiti-spring-7.1.0.M6.jar:na]
> at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:29) ~[activiti-engine-7.1.0.M6.jar:na]
> at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:44) ~[activiti-engine-7.1.0.M6.jar:na]
> at org.activiti.engine.impl.ProcessEngineImpl.(ProcessEngineImpl.java:68) ~[activiti-engine-7.1.0.M6.jar:na]
> at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.buildProcessEngine(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:847) ~[activiti-engine-7.1.0.M6.jar:na]
> at org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration.buildProcessEngine(SpringProcessEngineConfiguration.java:79) ~[activiti-spring-7.1.0.M6.jar:na]
> at org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean.getObject(ProcessEngineFactoryBean.java:57) ~[activiti-spring-7.1.0.M6.jar:na]
> at org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean.getObject(ProcessEngineFactoryBean.java:32) ~[activiti-spring-7.1.0.M6.jar:na]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:171) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
> ... 94 common frames omitted

ApplicationJava File:

```
package com.activiti.examples;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { org.activiti.spring.boot.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class ExamplesApplication {
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String datasourceUrl;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String datasourceUser;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String datasourcePassword;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().url(datasourceUrl).username(datasourceUser).password(datasourcePassword)
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExamplesApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Ativiti dependencies used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
    <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.0.M6</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
    <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>5.19.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

Spring Boot parent dependency:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
</parent>
```

Please help me in fixing this error.

Comment: It works when I use Activiti 6.0.0 version, but I would like to know how to fix this using Activiti 7.1.0.M6 version.

Comment: In Activiti engine maintain activiti release version in database table . Can you please manually change the version in ACT_GE_PROPERTY table and check issue solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62990495/getting-activiti-library-version-mismatch-error-when-used-7-1-0-m6-version-of-ac/65002485#comment111634158_62990495) by [Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8880333/developer) worked:

> In Activiti engine maintain activiti release version in database table . Can you please manually change the version in ACT_GE_PROPERTY table and check issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

i needed this to fix a setup, and was looking for exact parameter name to add.
the version is in field 'schema.version'.
if not existing at all :
insert into ACT_GE_PROPERTY VALUES ('schema.version','7.1.0-M6',1);